# docker push to docker hub results "unknown blob"

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerhub

I'm wondering what sporadically can result "unknown blob" when trying to run docker push registry/image:tag to docker hub.

This happens when running the docker build and then docker push, sporadically this can happen when running the commands manually.

Docker version: Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
Host: Ubuntu 16.04.
Docker registry: https://hub.docker.com/
in case docker push works, docker pull (also sporadically) will result:

> Error response from daemon: error parsing HTTP 404 response body:
>   invalid character 'p' after top-level value: "404 page not found\n"

Comment: Could be https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/1693? Started seeing the same intermittent error today too, looks like a Docker Hub Registry's partial outage.